# Create a View based on a SQL query in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Is there a way to create a View in Drupal based on a custom SQL query? I made the query to test my results and everything is fine, but don't wanna go through the whole process of trying to recreate the same via the View UI...

I need to generate it as a View to use the exposed filters and be able to create different display modes, that's why I don't simply execute the command and display the results.

I found an old module called "Query-Based Views (Q-Views)" that would do the job, but it looks deprecated.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of ways: You can use Relationships. So write own query, add views support and attach to current views...

Comment: not sure tu understand how to "attach" the query to the view?

Comment: Attach is mean create custom module, that support Views api. Start from here: http://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+views+api+custom+module

Comment: Using a custom module, will I be able to expose Sort Criterias? I juste need to allow the user to filter the list via some inputs.

Comment: Views can sort referenced tables as mysql query does this.